# iOS Development with Parse: "Forgot password" button outcome

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, callback, passwords

On the [current Parse iOS Guide](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-resetting-passwords): there's a method to be used whenever a user forgets a password:

PFUser.**requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground**("email@example.com")

This method apparently doesn't have a callback.

**How can I inform a certain user that the given email doesn't match any of the users in the database? (using Swift)**

P.S.: *I don't want to discuss if giving the user this information is useful or not*, I want to know how to handle this scenario in this specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple options. You can use the method `requestPasswordResetForEmail` which return a BOOL value indicating success or failure (user no found, for example).

There is also a block version of that `+ (void)requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:(NSString *)email block:(PF_NULLABLE PFBooleanResultBlock)block`

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to mention I was looking specifically for Swift syntax but I think I can manage that.